# Post-processing R Markdown-generated html files

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, mathjax

Is there a way to automatically apply some post-processing to `html` files generated from R Markdown?

For example, if we use MathJax to render LaTeX code (primarily in RStudio), the resulting html file includes `src=` links to load MathJax from a CDN. The problem is, we also need to be able to display these files on internal network without internet access, and those links need to be replaced to point to a local copy of MathJax.

It would be convenient if there was some hook that I could use to do that after the html file is generated, but I haven't been able to find any.

Comment: This example suggests that you can modify the behaviour upstream, asking Rmarkdown to have mathjax point to a URL: https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues/1593

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your post processing is specifically about MathJax, you might consider setting your output yaml to the following which will download local copies of libraries such as MathJax and link to them.

```
output: 
  html_document:
    self_contained: FALSE
    mathjax: local
```

Comment: Thank you, this solved this particular issue :)

Comment: I think if you wish to do other post processing a natural place to do so would be with a custom [pandoc filter](https://pandoc.org/filters.html). In short, these are scripts which run on the pandoc abstract syntax tree code just prior to pandoc creating the final output document.

Comment: Thank you, this looks like a very useful functionality, I'm definitely going to look into that. Do you know if it's possible to specify these in the YAML header, like with MathJax?

Comment: Yes, see the example [here](https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/docs/articles/lua-filters.html#lua-filter) about how to specify filters in the yaml.